# yii2 conflict in Urlmanager

Tags: yii2, blogs, friendly-url, yii2-urlmanager

Help me find a solution for subsections.

> Category: /blog/cat1/ /blog/cat/cat2/cat3/
>
> Detail: /blog/cat/cat2/cat3/element_code
>
> Subsection for tags in section 'blog': /blog/tag/ /blog/tag/some-tag/

I have this rules:

```
[
                'pattern' => '/blog/tags/<title>',
                'route' => 'blog/tag',
                'encodeParams' => false
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => 'blog/tags/',
                'route' => 'blog/tags/',
                'encodeParams' => false
            ],

            [
                'pattern' => 'blog/<category:[\w_\/-]+>/<slug>',
                'route' => 'blog/post',
                'encodeParams' => false
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => 'blog/<category:[\w_\/-]+>',
                'route' => 'blog/category',
                'encodeParams' => false
            ],
```

But in tag section (/blog/tag/) Category controller starts, no Tag controller.
What to do in this case?

Comment: Are you sure it's `'route' => 'blog/tag',` not `'route' => 'blog/tags',`,  as pattern has `/tags` not `/tag` value.

Comment: Hello! yes, in route 'blog/tag' i have controller Tag for view all posts by some tag (like TagPosts). But, if i delete this section for detail by tag, I still have a mistake with the section /blog/tags/

Comment: What is the value of `enableStrictParsing` in your config? Is it true/false?

Comment: Turn it on and off - nothing changes...

Comment: You have `tags` in your pattern, while you're accessing `blog/tags` URL.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was different. The rules are all correct. Thank you for wanting to help!

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remained.  @rob006 What did you mean in your last message?

Comment: You're requesting `/blog/tag/some-tag/` while your rule expects `/blog/tags/some-tag/`. `tag` vs `tags`.

Comment: even if I leave [
                    'pattern' => 'blog/tags/<title>',
                    'route' => 'blog/tags/',
                    'encodeParams' => false,
                ], the category controller will override